# getting comments from a youtube video - GData objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, youtube, gdata

I am developing an iPhone application that requires use of YouTube..I wanted to know how can I get comments from a video? I have looked around but have had no luck...sorry if this question is a bit open ended

Answer (score 1):

You should check [YouTube API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html). In this API [Video comments feed](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Comments_Feeds) is available.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Objective-C library for Google Data APIs](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/).

It includes a [sample application](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/YouTubeSample/YouTubeSampleWindowController.m) showing how to use the YouTube Data API.

Answer (score 0):

```
GDataEntryYouTubeVideo * video = {your video entry here};

GDataServiceGoogleYouTube * youtubeService = [[GDataServiceGoogleYouTube alloc] init];

youtubeService.userAgent = @"App Name";
youtubeService.youTubeDeveloperKey = @"your developer key";

GDataQueryYouTube * query = [[GDataQueryYouTube alloc] init];

query.startIndex = 1;
query.maxResults = 50;
query.feedURL = video.comment.feedLink.URL;

[youtubeService fetchFeedWithQuery:query
                      completionHandler:^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataFeedBase *feed, NSError *error)
{
    if(error)
    {
        return;
    }

    GDataFeedYouTubeComment * commentFeed = (GDataFeedYouTubeComment*)feed;

    NSArray * comments = feed.entries;
}];
```